# Output of SVM changes depending on sign of classes

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I want to train a non-linear SVM with a dataset like this:
[image]

In the purple samples, `y = -1`. In the yellow ones, `y = 1`.

Then, I'm fitting the data into my SVM:

```
def rbf_kernel(X1, X2, gamma=0.3):
    diff = X1[:, np.newaxis, :] - X2[np.newaxis, :, :]
    norms = np.sum(diff ** 2, axis=-1)
    return np.exp(-gamma * norms)

class SVM():
    def __init__(self, kernel=rbf_kernel, C=0.8):
        self.kernel = kernel
        self.C = C

    def fit(self, X, y, X_test, y_test, learning_rate=0.000003, epochs=10000):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        
        self.alpha = np.zeros(n_samples)
        self.b = 0
        self.x_train = X
        self.y_train = y
        self.epochs = []
        self.accuracies = []

        K = self.kernel(self.x_train, self.x_train)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
                
                pred = np.dot(K, self.alpha*self.y_train) + self.b
                error = np.maximum(0, 1 - pred * y)
                loss = np.mean(error) 
                
                d_alpha = np.mean(np.dot(-y * (pred < 1), y * K))
                d_b = np.mean(sum(-y * (pred < 1)))
                
                self.alpha -= learning_rate * d_alpha
                self.b -= learning_rate * d_b

                if epoch % 10 == 0:
                  print(f'Epoch {epoch}, loss: {loss:.4f}')
                  acc = self.accuracy(X_test, y_test)
                  print(f'Accuracy: {acc}')
                self.epochs.append(epoch)
                self.accuracies.append(acc)

    def predict(self, X):
        K = self.kernel(X, self.x_train)
        pred = np.dot(K, self.alpha * self.y_train) + self.b
        return np.sign(pred)
    
    def accuracy(self, X, y):
      y_pred = self.predict(X)
      accuracy = np.mean(y == y_pred)
      return round(accuracy, 3)
```

With this dataset, I have no problem. Accuracy is 0.997.

I decide then to swap the sign of the classes, like this:
[image]

Accuracy now doesn't improve. It only does when i swap the signs of the weights-updating formula:

```
self.alpha += learning_rate * d_alpha
self.b += learning_rate * d_b
```

Does anyone have an explanation to this? I don't understand why swapping the classes involves a sign swap as well.